# Get Robo test to fill out a SearchView inside an Action bar menu item?

Tags: automated-tests, integration-testing, firebase-test-lab

I want to use Firebase test lab's Robo test to fill out the search field in my app so that there are results for the Robo test to correctly crawl through my app.

I tried filling in the id of the search view action in the Robo test -> Advanced Options -> Additional fields section as in below screenshot, but Robo test could not find my searchview. The search view is an always-visible action in the menu set on my `AppCompatActivity`'s action bar.

[image: Additional fields]

Any suggestions / thoughts are welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using the Robo auto completion parameters, you have to provide the name of the resource ID that corresponds with the EditText you want to populate.  You can't put arbitrary values in there - they must be unique names that end up in your app's R class.  If you are having problems finding that name, you should use a tools such as the Android Device Monitor's [Hierarchy Viewer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html) to discover those views and their names.

Comment: So you're saying it'd work if I used `R.id.searchview` instead (which is the id of the particular view)? Or should I use the integer id!?

Comment: No, just the name.  Your question doesn't show any XML or anything that helps us see what you actually used when you built the layout.